# numerical methods sketches

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Can someone show graphically in the tx-plane of illustrating the process of moving from (tk,xk) to (tk+1, xk+1) in

-Euler's method

-Improved Euler's method

and RK4?

I understand the formulas but cannot see it nicely graphically

Answer (score 3):

Here is the problem from an earlier question of yours.

Euler's method $x' = x, x(0) = 1$, step size = $0.1$

All you are doing is plotting $x(t)$ versus $t$.

For example, we know the exact values for:

$t = 0, 0.1, 0.2 \ldots 1.0$ of $x(t) = e^{t}.$

Now plot that alongside the same $t$ values the Euler's provides and you get something that looks like:

[image]

Is that clear?

All of them are exactly the same in this regard. You are just showing the exact graph next to the approximate one from the numerical method.

Here is a variant that shows the points on the plot $(t_k, x_k)$ for the ten steps. If this is not what you are looking for, you are going to have to explain it.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the answer in general, of moving from (tk,xk) to (tk+1, xk+1) in each of the 3 methods above. Could you please provide a sketch on it, with the differentials? Thanks

Comment: No, just showing the picture in the tx-plane that illustrates the process of moving from (tk,xk) to the next step (tk+1,xk+1) in each of the three methods

Comment: In general, looking at the graph of the point (tk,xk) how does it look like when we are at the next point (tk+1,xk+1) in each of the three methods?

Comment: Great job! Nice follow up conversation. Let's hope it clicks!