# Graphical analysis of the 4th order Runge-Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

Can someone represent the 4th order Runge-Kutta method graphically when iterating from $(x_k,t_k)$ to $(x_{k+1},t_{k+1})$?

Comment: Did you mean like the graphic [*here*](http://jmckennonmth212s09.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/runge-kutta-method-vs-euler-method/) or [*this*](http://www.boomer.org/c/p3/c10/c1003.html)?

Comment: Yes, the first link was very good. Amzoti, could you also please fill in the details for the nonlinear DE question? I worked on it, but having some trouble using a computer software to generate results for Euler, Implicit EUler with the 3 different step sizes. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the graphic [*here*](http://jmckennonmth212s09.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/runge-kutta-method-vs-euler-method/).

Also, you can merge/correlate that diagram in with the graphics I added [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367937/numerical-methods-sketches/367942#367942).

Comment: Yay!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Kind of slowish tonight...

Comment: Could be...we'll still get some action with finals, etc...but it will be interesting to see what summer will be like.